# How to control the table to small size when the screen is large using bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<table class="col-lg-6 table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-responsive" id="tab">
```

I had included col-lg-6 to table.Even though the table is displaying full screen length

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/11436/

Once check the above fiddle

Comment: obviously `col-lg-6` is for large screen so what do you need from us ?

Comment: I was searching for When the screen is large the table must be displayed in a small size

Comment: you are using two `class` in your code fix it and you will get your output

Comment: just make your code like this  `<table class="col-lg-6 table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-responsive">`

Comment: I have tried by doing it..the table  length is not getting reduced when the screen is large

Comment: `<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-responsive col-lg-3 col-md-6" id="tab">` control it using something like this

Comment: what is your screen size of your pc ? is it large or medium?

Comment: if you use `md` istead of `lg` than you will get the output @NagaBhavani

Comment: Bootstrap is nothing but in any screen size the content should be adjusted...Then what is the need of screen size ?

Comment: in `bootstrap.min.css` you can find the `width` of the column so if that style is applying than how it will adjust the size you should give custom `width` for that

Answer (score 2):

Always use class name 'table-responsive', it will help you a lot in responsive.

```
<div class='table-responsive'>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-responsive col-lg-6" id="tab">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should figure out about your screen size first.
Like:

1. Large Screen (lg) has `> 1170px` screen size
2. Medium Screen (md) has `> 970px` to `< 1170px` screen size
3. Small Screen (sm) has `> 750px` to `< 970px` screen size
4. Extra Small Screen (xs) has `< 750px` screen size

And according to this you can apply the class like
`col-lg`, `col-md`, `col-sm`, `col-xs`

Answer (score 1):

I have used div ..I have written table code between and included col-lg-6 to div.It worked.

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote is wrong. The correct way is:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-responsive col-lg-6" id="tab">
```

You had an attribute inside another and the quotation mark (`"`) broke it.